# Why syntax error with visudo ¿?

Tags: sudo

What's wrong with this line of sudoers file?

```
%test ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/supervisorctl status test, /usr/bin/supervisorctl start test, /usr/bin/supervisorctl stop test, /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart test, /usr/bin/supervisorctl status test-dev, /usr/bin/supervisorctl start test-dev, /usr/bin/supervisorctl stop test-dev, /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart test-dev, service nginx restart
```

Can't fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

solved.

I forgot the /usr/sbin/ before service :|